# Can't locate Net/SSH/Expect.pm in ubuntu?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssh

I am fairly new to scripting with perl. I am trying to ssh into a server and perform some commands. I have to provide a username and password.
I try to use Net::SSH::Expect in perl, but when i run my perl program,
I have try this,

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
cpanm Net::SSH::Perl
```

but still get the  error msg as below,

```
Can't locate Net/SSH/Expect.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SSH::Expect module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /home/hsuan/inms/get/get_mac.plx line 9.
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/hsuan/inms/get/get_mac.plx line 9.

Is there an easier way to install it than downloading, untarring, making, etc?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be packaged as a Debian package if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

***You need Net::SSH::Expect***, but you're installing Net::SSH::Perl.

[Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) and [Net::SSH::Expect](https://metacpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Expect/view/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod) are different libraries. When a Perl module is named "Perl" that just means it's 100% Perl and does not require a C compiler.

Install Net::SSH::Expect, like it says. `cpanm Net::SSH::Expect`.

---

> I have to provide a username and password

This is better solved by using ssh keys and an ssh-agent.